# Spark: writing data to place that is being read from without loosing data

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

Help me please to understand how can I write data to the place that is also being read from without any issue, using EMR and S3.
So I need to read partitioned data, find old data, delete it, write new data back and I'm thinking about 2 ways here:

1. Read all data, apply a filter, write data back with save option SaveMode.Overwrite. I see here one major issue - before writing it will delete files in S3, so if EMR cluster goes down by some reason after deletion but before writing - all data will be lost. I can use dynamic partition but that would mean that in such situation I'm gonna lost data from 1 partition.
2. Same as above but write to the temp directory, then delete original, move everything from temp to original. But as this is S3 storage it doesn't have move operation and all files will be copied, which can be a bit pricy(I'm going to work with 200GB of data).

Is there any other way or am I'm wrong in how spark works?

Comment: The way the object store connectors (s3a etc) do renames is through a COPY call within the S3 infrastructure. If source and dest buckets are in the same region (or the same bucket), you pay $0 for the amount of data, just have to wait for the copy to complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not wrong. The process of deleting a record from a table on EMR/Hadoop is painful in the ways you describe and more. It gets messier with failed jobs, small files, partition swapping, slow metadata operations...

There are several formats, and file protocols that add transactional capability on top of a table stored S3. The open Delta Lake (https://delta.io/) format, supports transactional deletes, updates, merge/upsert and does so very well. You can read & delete (say for GDPR purposes) like you're describing. You'll have a transaction log to track what you've done.

On point 2, as long as you have a reasonable # of files, your costs should be modest, with data charges at ~$23/TB/mo. However, if you end with too many small files, then the API costs of listing the files, fetching files can add up quickly. Managed Delta (from Databricks) will help speed of many of the operations on your tables through compaction, data caching, data skipping, z-ordering

Disclaimer, I work for Databricks....